# How to select a particular value from a <select> element?

Tags: javascript

I have come across `<select>` (drop down list) in HTML in the learning process. I learnt how to code a `<select>` drop down list.

How can I perform a particular action (in my case I am performing a mathematical operation) when a value in the `<select>` is chosen?

Comment: Start by [Learning JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Comment: if google can solve problem, then it is not good for SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of ways.

I would suggest putting a onchange event attribute and give the  element an ID.

eg.

```
<select id ="example1" onchange="example_function()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Now that you have done that you can goto your JS and use the follow.

```
var droplist
var droplist_value
function example_function(){
 droplist = document.getElementbyID("example1")
 droplist_value = droplist.value
}
```

You can now use the droplist_value as you want.